# Lighting Data Table with large data set lagging on chrome browser

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-datatable, lwc-dom

So I have this requirement to show folder and report as a hierarchy in **LWC** (used lightning tree for the same with custom icons for folders and reports.) and on click of any report, we fetch the report rows (initial we only get 2000 report rows if it is more than 2000 we hit show all button). When clicked on a report it shows little bit of lag in Mozilla/edge/opera browser but in chrome, it becomes unresponsive for a long time and then after it starts to work again but with lags. My question is that how do I optimize it for chrome?

**Note**: Please don't suggest lazy loading. When it's used I cannot select all rows - lazy loading won't bring all rows at a time and we have this req of selecting all. I.e. if 50 k records are there, the user should be able to select all at once hence lazy loading is removed.

Comment: Can you share some of your code? Mostly the apex method (including query) and the wire adapter (or however you handled) in lwc?

Comment: My question would be why would you want to show 50K rows? If the purpose is just to select all, then just say **Showing 2K of 50K records. Click to select all 50K** and do the actual query in Apex. If the purpose is allow user to select some records, better use pagination logic and store selected records in cache

Comment: Hi Manjit there is a business requirement for the same reports that can have these much of records in them hence for stress testing we need to do so. And report data is not queried directly from apex. and on data table i have no idea if on click of Select All can capture the event that would trigger my js so that i can run logic to fetch all the records and just throw x number of records on ui. If you know any way to capture select all event of lightning data table in LWC please let me know.

Comment: HI, @stackasaur I m doing an imperative apex call on click of a report in tree . I am passing report id in that apex call it would return report metadata to me. this api response is purely processed in js of LWC and processed rows are then displayed in table. the first click would only fetch at max 2k records. Now we would press show all if required by end user and  apex call would keep taking place and keep appending the returned rows in a temp object and when all the rows are fetched we assign this temp object data to my main variable that is responsible for data in the data table.

Comment: @stackasaur Note: No unnecessary processing is taking place both in apex/lwc it is taking place as far as i know in the optimal way otherwise all other browsers would have caused same issue. Apex call would keep taking place upon hitting show all untiil or unless all rows are fetched from that report.

Comment: Rakshit, for that you can check the size of the selected records variable exposed by data table. If the size matches the rows shown on the UI, user has clicked select all or simply give a separate button to select all.